# DirectSound using MinGW: undefined reference 'DirectSoundCreate8'

Tags: c++, clion, mingw-w64, directsound

I want to use the DirectSound API (from DirectX) to process the audio Windows outputs. To do so, I created "libdsound.a" as described in the following paragraphs, because it seems like I cannot use .dll s or .lib s for the MinGW g++ compiler.
I installed the DirectX SDK and copied the dsound.lib to a folder called "directsound". From the mingw-w64 repository, I downloaded dsound.h and dsound.def to the directory "directsound" as well (all files I used were for x86).
Following [this guide](http://tsubaki.hatenablog.com/entry/20110115/1295080728) I used the dlltool command line to create the libdsound.a:

```
dlltool -d dsound.def -l libdsound.a
```

In CLion, I set up CMake in CMakeLists.txt the following way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(fourier)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

link_directories(PATHTOTHISDIR/directsound)
include_directories(PATHTOTHISDIR/directsound)

add_executable(fourier main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(fourier dsound)
```

CLion says the CMakeLists.txt file is fine. Every time I try to compile the program, building and linking seems to work fine, but then I get the following error message:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fourier.dir/main.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable fourier.exe
CMakeFiles\fourier.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
PATHTOPROJECT/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `DirectSoundCreate8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

This is how main.cpp (the only source file) looks like:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libdsound.a")

#include <windows.h>
#include <dsound.h>

int main() {
    LPDIRECTSOUND8 directsound;
    DirectSoundCreate8(NULL, &directsound, NULL);

    WAVEFORMATEX waveformat;
    // ....
```

**EDIT** Was able to resolve it thanks to the advice of VTT. The way I created the libdsound.a was wrong. It should've been done like this:

```
dlltool -D dsound.dll -d dsound.def -l libsound.a -k
```

I should have also created the .def file on my own.

```
reimp -c -d dsound.lib
```

The dsound.dll should be placed in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: *"I cannot use .dll s or .lib s for the MinGW g++ compiler"* but this is essentially what you are doing. You need to link .dll implementing `DirectSoundCreate8` and you've made an import library for this purpuse (with `.a` extension though). *"building and linking seems to work fine"* build actually fails on linking stage.

Comment: @VTT Thank you. I'll look into that

Comment: I didn't really suggest anything, I've just stated that you are actually doing it correctly. Maybe that `dsound.h and dsound.def` is not exactly right or something. Try checking whether generated import library actually exports anything.

Comment: @VTT It's working now. The way I created the libdsound.a was wrong. See "EDIT" section

Comment: Don't put answers in questions. Post your answer below. You are allowed to answer your own questions.

Comment: @RossRidge I can't answer any questions because of an answer ban...